# Equivalent of VBA TRIM function Excel with worksheet function

Tags: vba, excel, trim

I know that the TRIM function as worksheet function and as VBA function returns different results:

- the worksheet function removes all spaces from a text string except for single spaces between words
- while the VBA function only removes leading and trailing spaces.

There is a way to emulate the VBA behavior with worksheet functions, WITHOUT a custom VBA function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using only worksheet functions you could try this for a text string in A1:

```
=REPLACE(LEFT(A1,MATCH(2,1/(MID(A1,MMULT(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),1)<>" "))),1,FIND(LEFT(TRIM(A1)),A1)-1,"")
```

Finding the position of the last character that's not a space is not straightforward due to the lack of string reverse worksheet functions.

If you don't want to use VBA it's much simpler to use *Data|Text to Columns* with the options:

1. Fixed Width
2. No break lines
3. Destination: B1

which also removes leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: +1 nice! At first I thought MMULT was superfluous, but on closer inspection it removes the need for array entry. Was that your intention?

Comment: @andyholaday: Thanks and yes, that was exactly the intention. Surprisingly, in spite of the extra function call, the MMULT version recalculates over twice as fast as the array formula equivalent in Excel 2010 (tested by copying down many cells - though there didn't seem to be any difference in Excel 2003).

Answer (score 2):

> the worksheet function removes all spaces from a text string except for single spaces between words

No that is not completely true :) Worksheet `TRIM` function does not remove the nonbreaking space character (`&nbsp;`). To remove the nonbreaking space character, you have a different function called `CLEAN()`

If you want to use the Worksheet Function `Trim` in VBA then you can use it like this

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Range("A1").Value)
```

In Excel Worksheet you can use `=TRIM()`

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is a worksheet function that removes only the leading and trailing spaces. Any idea?

Comment: I think I may know what you are referring to. Are you by any chance referring to a case where cell has a space created by Alt + Enter?

Comment: No Siddharth, I've a string like this: "string with one or    more spaces  ". The result for TRIM(string) in a excel cell would be "string with one or more spaces". the VBA TRIM function will returns "string with one or    more spaces"...

Comment: Sorry but both your result strings look same to me? Do you have a sample where I can see what you mean? If you want, you can upload an excel file with the string in say cell A1 so that we can see what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function in VBA that you can refer to in your worksheet.

For example:

```
Public Function MyTrim(text As String) As String    
    MyTrim = Trim(text)    
End Function
```

Then in your worksheet, assuming the text you want to trim is in cell A1:

```
=MyTrim(A1)
```

Comment: Thanks Pete, but I was looking for a solution without using a custom VBA function. Regs

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  The "Without custom VBA function" was edited onto the question after I posted this answer...

Comment: @PeteOakey - I have removed my downvote in light of that clarification